# How to find the location of Cell with Value "Section B" in Range ("B:B")?

Tags: excel, range, vba

[image]

How to find the Location of Cell with "Section B" in the above image as (BX)?

Comment: Define a named range for cell which has text `Section B`. Even if the more rows are added to section A you can easily find the location of `Section B` with syntax  `Range("<named range>").Address`. Read more about named range [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/named.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will show a message box of Section B's address.

```
Sub FindSectionB()
    Dim TargetRng As String
    TargetRng = ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Find(What:="Section B").Address
    MsgBox TargetRng
End Sub
```

UPDATE: If only row is needed, change

> .Find(What:="Section B").Address

to this:

> .Find(What:="Section B").Row

Comment: @BK201... Thanks for the above code.
But I want the X alone...
Say for the above 
    TargetRng = "$B$12"
But I want the integer 12 alone to be retrieved.

Comment: @Vikram Use `split("$B$12","$")(2)` OR `ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Find(What:="Section B").Row`

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Updated my answer above to reflect the Row as well.